# Use Unsupervised Nearest Neighbors with NaN

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, nan, knn

I want to use unsupervised nearest neighbors and I have NaN in my data. I want that when a feature for a record is NaN, it does not count for the distance with any other record. Filling NaN with 0, would make it close to other records with a value close of 0 and far from value far from 0, so it would not work.

I created a Euclidean metric that does that since NaN propagate for - and **, but are 0 for nansum. However, I am still getting an error due to the NaN.

Is there any way to fix this error? I would consider using another module than sklearn if needed.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
def metric(x1,x2):
    return np.nansum((x1-x2)**2) 
nn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=10, metric=metric, n_jobs=-1)
nn.fit(x)

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

What I mean is that I want that if a record has a NaN for the 10th feature (for example), the 10th feature does not count in the distance with any other record, so the record will be equally close to any other record no matter if they have a -1, 0, 13 or any other number for the 10th feature.

Dropping records with NaN would not work, it would actually drop all records. Setting NaN to 0 or any other numbers would not work either. I want to mask the NaN out of the sum of the distances for all features.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'don't count for the distance with any other record'? 
do you wish to simply drop the records that contain NaN anywhere?

Comment: No, I want that if a record has a NaN for the 10th feature, the 10th feature do not count in the distance with any other record, so the record will be equally close to any other record no matter if they have a -1, 0, 13 or any other number for the 10th feature.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when implementing a kNN classifier for data with missing values. When calling the fit() method, scikit-learn checks if there are nans in the data and then raises the error. I didnt found a solution and ended up with writing my own kNN classifier.

Assuming your data is scaled to 0 mean and unity variance, replacing nan with 0 is not a good idea as you already stated. So, I also decided to ignore a feature in the distance computation between two samples if at least one value is nan. However, this increases the chance that samples with many missing values have small distances to other samples. So it makes sense to normalize the distance by the number of features where both samples are complete and only consider samples as nearest neighbors when a minimum amount of features have values in both samples.